# Rename a cluster of VMs in Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I have a cluster of VMs called test-m, test-w-0, test-w-1... , do you know how I can change the test prefix to something else without deleting the cluster?

I have fully written my question, but stackoverflow wants me to write more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataproc doesn't support cluster renaming. You have to create a new one.